# Why is white space not found in my NodeJS program?

Tags: string, whitespace, indexof

For some obscure reason, my `str.split(" ")` command doesn't seem to work. I've been trying to debug the situation for a while now and can't seem to find the solution.  Let me start off by saying that, unfortunately, I can't replicate the error. I've tried creating a JSFiddle, but it works correctly.

**Here's my problem**: I've got a JSObject "library" over which I'm looping to create MongoDocuments and during this "construction" I get the following:

```
if (payload[i].asking) {
        let price = payload[i].asking
        price = price.substring(1, price.length);
        console.log(price);
        console.log(price.indexOf(" "));
        const priceArr = price.split(" ");
        console.log(priceArr);
        price = priceArr[0];
        currency = priceArr[1];
        listing.set('asking', price);
        listing.set('currency', currency);
      }
```

*where*:

- `payload` is the full JSObject "library"
- `[i]` the current JSObject
- and `asking`, the key I'm working on, in this particular place of the code.

And here's the result:

```
500.00 eur
-1
[ '500.00 eur' ]
950.00 eur
-1
[ '950.00 eur' ]
5,000.00 usd
-1
[ '5,000.00 usd' ]
250.00 usd
-1
[ '250.00 usd' ]
800.00 usd
-1
[ '800.00 usd' ]
899.00 usd
-1
[ '899.00 usd' ]
3,500.00 usd
-1
[ '3,500.00 usd' ]
2,800.00 usd
-1
[ '2,800.00 usd' ]
2,250.00 usd
-1
[ '2,250.00 usd' ]
3,750.00 usd
-1
[ '3,750.00 usd' ]
1,500.00 usd
-1
[ '1,500.00 usd' ]
5,800.00 usd
-1
[ '5,800.00 usd' ]
2,500.00 usd
-1
[ '2,500.00 usd' ]
```

So I understand why `price.split(" ")` doesn't work: I apparently have no *white space* in the first place **`(indexOf(" ") === -1)`** but I'm not sure why and what's happening. `payload[i].asking` is a *string* alright (`price.substring` proves it) but I don't understand why this *white space* doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found an alternative, using regex, even though it doesn't solve the exact problem I describe per se:

```
const priceArr = price.split(/(\s+)/)
```

It might help someone else...